# Layout inside QtGui.QTabWidget PySide

Tags: python, qt, layout, pyqt, pyside

How can I add a layout but not a widget inside a `QtGui.QTabWidget`? Something like this:

```
    tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget()
    tabs.addTab(QtGui.QVBoxLayout(), "Layout")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't add layouts to a tab widget, you add widgets.

The simplest choice here would be a [`QFrame`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qframe.html) (or even a plain `QWidget`), to which you can set whatever layout you want.

Comment: Thank you. This is execly what I need.